# Unit test ignore log level

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I have a log level defined in my `config/app.php` to `emergency`.

```
'log' => 'syslog',
'log_level' => env('LOG_LEVEL','warning'),
```

Throughout my applications i have `Log::info('info')` in several places. Meaning that info should be ignore because the log level set to emergency. This works great when i actually run the application, the problem is When i run unit tests with `phpunit`. The log level is ignored logs everything.

Anyone have an idea why this could happen?

Comment: Do you have a `config/testing/app.php` file?

Comment: I have a config/app.php, without testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some versions of Monolog (I'm not seeing this on the master branch now), Monology outputs to stderr when no handler is set:

https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/1.22.0/src/Monolog/Logger.php#L288-L290

Pushing a handler onto Monolog, like the NULL one, will supress the logging:

https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/NullHandler.php